# linux SORT utility: setting EOR and EOF

Tags: bash

How can I set what the EOR and EOF is for the sort utility to use.

For example:

- EOR (End of Record) by default is \n, but I want \n\r (not \r\n).
- EOF (End of File) by default is 0x05 or \n, but I want "END".

Comment: _"EOF (End of File) by default is 0x05"_ ?? No, that's just the ctrl-D that you type at the terminal to indicate the end of file. Inside the file itself, there is no ctrl-D character. The end of the file is just the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to pre-process your file so that it has the expected end-of-line character, and is truncated at the right place, before sorting it. The following uses `sed` to do that:

```
sed 's/\r//;/END/,$d' t.txt | sort
```

What this does is:

1. Remove all `\r` from each line. That way, we end up with lines having just `\n` as line terminator.
2. Delete all lines from the first line containing "END" until the end of the file.
3. Pass the result to `sort`.

Comment: What if a record can have multiple \n?

Comment: @blackknight I'll have to think about that and get back to you